# openshift: maven compiler error : Base64 can not find the symbol

Tags: java, maven, base64, openshift-cartridge

I am deploying webapp to the openshift cloud.

While compiling the resources by maven automatically after deploying, it shows `Base64: symbol not found`
However when I maven compile it on my Pc, their are no errors and build is successfull. I tried to change `Base64` from `java.util` to `apache.commons.codecs`. The error is still there while deploying and it successfully runs at my local machine

Following is the `pom.xml`

```
           <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

 <dependencies>
<dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

> Should I place the commons-codec jar in WEB_INF directory. i read the solution somewhere but was not sure about it.
>   please suggest a solution. Thank you

```
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Please provide the stack trace for both cases.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you're using JDK 8 on your machine, but JDK 7 where the error is happening as [java.util.Base64](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) is only available since Java SE 8.

I recommend to use the same Java version on both machines.

Otherwise you should consider [cross-compiling](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/javac.html#BHCIJIEG). Just setting the source and target level is not enough, as you can see, as you're still able to call new APIs.

Comment: I am using apache.commons.codes. Are they also dependent on java8 ?

Comment: You mentioned java.util.Base64. Please provide the error stack trace for both cases. Did you replace all references to java.util.Base64?

Comment: "I tried to change Base64 from java.util to apache.commons.codecs. The error is still there while deploying and it successfully runs at my local machine".. I already mentioned that I switched from `java.util` to `apache.commons`. Anyway, i solved the issue. basically issues are with java.util. `apache.commons` works.. Thank you for ur time

Comment: @Sheikh_Irshad I've read that you tried that. Again, please provide the stack trace for both cases or at least the one where you're using Apache Commons.